# How to draw repeating *horizontal* dashed lines using CSS conic-gradient?

Tags: css

I have just read [how to draw dashed and solid vertical lines with css gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72936022/how-to-draw-dashed-and-solid-vertical-lines-with-css-gradient/)

But i have to say, that despite reading the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/conic-gradient) over and over again, and reading the suggested code, I have no clue how it works. The syntax of that is impenetrable.

I asked a follow up question on that thread asking how to make the lines horizontal, but the admins saw fit to delete it.

Is anybody with ninja level CSS skills able to help with this request which *should* be simple, but which the CSS standards authors have made difficult?

This is the requirement: [horizontal lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNGmw.png)

I created a Codepen in which I tried to manipulate that CSS, but just changing any attribute breaks the output in what appears to be unpredictable ways.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another "impenetrable syntax" same as the other (I am the author of the other by the way)

```css
html {
  --c: #222; /* color */
  --t: 2px; /* thickness */
  --d: 10px; /* control the dashes */
  --g: 50px;  /* distance between vertical lines */
  --w: 150px; /* distance between horizontal lines*/
 
  background:
    conic-gradient(from 90deg at var(--t) var(--t),#0000 25%,var(--c) 0)
     0 0/var(--w) calc(4*var(--g)),
    conic-gradient(at 50% var(--t),#0000 75%,var(--c) 0)
     0 0/var(--d) var(--g);

}
```

This is not simple and the CSS authors didn't make this difficult. I am just using an optimized code that you can easily control using CSS variables but you cannot easily adjust to create another kind of grid. You need a different code for that

Comment: Thanks.

But why the sarcasm quotes?

Comment: @NIge it's not sarcasm, I am quoting *your* words.

Comment: OK, so after the actual `conic-gradient` spec, the extra properties are, I assume other `background-xxx` properties like `background-position` etc

`0 0/var(--d) var(--g)`

What are these properties? You say it's not difficult. But I have read the MDN docs, and I have taken your code and changed values to see what happens.

But what happens is quite unrecognizable. I cannot *tell* if what I have changed just changed the `background-position-x` or something else. It just changes to.... something.

Comment: @NIge *You say it's not difficult.* --> I said "this is not simple" so it's difficult and I cannot explain all what is going on here. I write articles (https://css-articles.com/) and share CSS tips (https://css-tip.com/) if you want to dig into such complex stuff. A good one to start with: https://verpex.com/blog/website-tips/how-to-create-background-pattern-using-css-conic-gradient

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif) for helping me achieve my goal.

For anybody else struggling to comprehend, I ended up with

```
background-image : conic-gradient(at 50% 1px, transparent 75%, var(--line-color) 0turn);
```

Where `1px` is the line height.

The explicit `0turn` might help explain how the gradient works. I'm still figuring out how that makes a "-".

The following background style properties which were embedded in the `background` property in the original answer, I preferred to specify separately in my own CSS so as to be clearer to maintainers (and my future self)

```
background-size     : 10px calc(var(--row-height) + 1px);
background-position : 0px var(--row-height);
```

Where `10px` serves as the total width which the dash and line occupy. The `50%` x start position of the gradient meaning it is an even pattern.

So what we are creating is a 10 by (row height + 1) block which repeats in both the `x` and `y` dimensions.